# How to execute a method with property from xml string using C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, delegates, task

I would like to develop a workflow designer or BPM using C# with asp.net mvc core. Please help me on how to run methods from xml file without using reflection.

Sample link which i got below

[Reading XML and executing functions dynamically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530155/reading-xml-and-executing-functions-dynamically-using-c-sharp)

- I would like to use drag and drop components - ex : copy file, Move file
- While saving this components or a workflow , it will be saved in xml format
- Ex : `<Myworkflow><method><CopyFile><prop><from></from><to></to></prop></CopyFile></method><Myworkflow>`
- Execute/call a predefined function written - sequentially based on this XML with parameters

Kindly help me with resources which will dynamically call methods with parameters without reflection.

Cheers

Comment: Check [Windows Workflow Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/)

Comment: Suppose you want to write a custom thing (otherwise @Eldar's suggestion is probably worth exploring) - I don't think you can completely avoid using reflection at some stage. Why is it an issue?

Comment: As far my research or googling - Reflection seems very slow and recommendation is to use delegates. Please suggest or help me with basic examples of how to achieve this. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: LINQ Expression trees might be an option for you. It still requires you to reflect over certain parts of your types, but then you get to keep  the compiled delegates and run them at near native speed